# Documentation for python XMIparser API not found

Tags: python, uml, xmi, papyrus

I need to convert a xmi file from a UML model createed with [Papyrus](https://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/) into python class and objects. I found [xmiparser api](https://pypi.org/project/xmiparser/), but I didn´t found any documentation or tutorial to use it. Is this API deprecated?

It has some useful methods like `xmiparser.getElementByTagName()` but I don´t know how to use the API to import the xmi file for example.

I tried to use [PyXMI](http://pyxmi.sourceforge.net/index.html) but it didn´t work like I expected.

Comment: You could do all the parsing by hand, but it will be very painful if you want to parse everything properly.  I know that it is usually badly seen to propose another solution to the initial request, but I developed '[pyuml2](https://github.com/pyecore/pyuml2)' which is an implementation of UML2 in Python (with XMI support) which aims to be compliant with the Eclipse/Papyrus implementation. The implementation is still a WIP on some points but is easier to handle than doing the parsing by hand, and it provides facilities to manipulate the produced model.